# How to get every post inside nested database from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello there I have nested database with collection(quotes)>document(uid)>collection(quote)>document(id)

When I try to fetch the quote, I can only fetch for current user. How can I loop through uid and get everything inside quote collection for every user.

My code for fetching the quotes:

```
func fetchQuote() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        
  Firestore.firestore().collection("quotes")
  .document(uid).collection("quote")
  .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
          
  if let error = error {
                print("There was an error while fetch the quotes.")
                return
            }
            
            querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                if change.type == .added{
                    let data = change.document.data()
                self.quotes.append(.init(documentId:change.document.documentID, data: data))
                }
            })
            
   
        }
    }
```

I tried  to remove the following:

```
.document(uid).collection("quote")
```

Comment: If you want a list of UIDs, you will have to query the quotes collection separately and iterate all the documents to find all the UIDs. You cannot combine queries between collections - subcollections are actually completely independent from their parent collection except by the way they are organized.

Comment: Can I then access to quote collection from UIDs?

Comment: I just need to access the subcollection quote, but for all users, not just one

Comment: Also, when I just try to get quotes collection and all documents with .getDocuments() function, it just don't work, it always print empty... sorry for spam, but this really bothering me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is use of `.collectionGroup()`

```
 Firestore.firestore().collectionGroup("quote").getDocuments(){ querySnapshot, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("There was an error \(error)")
        return
    }
    
    
    querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
        if change.type == .added{
            let data = change.document.data()
            self.quotes.append(.init(documentId:change.document.documentID, data: data))
        }
    })
}
```